# ELK data ingestion: elasticsearch treat text as boolean even though mapping says type is 'text'

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I'm using ELK 7.4.1 with docker from [here](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk), and I need to ingest data from MySQL database. One of the tables has this 'status' field defined as `varchar(128)`. I used logstash jdbc plugin for this purpose, but when I started the docker image I saw a lot of warning messages saying `org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse field [status] of type [boolean] in document with id '34ZXb24BsfR1FhttyYWt'. Preview of field's value: 'Success'"`. What puzzles me, however, is that the mapping seems to be correct: `"status": { "type": "text", ... }` and the data seems to be successfully ingested.

I even tried to manually create the index, and then put the mapping before ingesting the data, but that didn't help either.

Any ideas why?

Adding more info:

**Table definition**

```
CREATE TABLE records (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  status varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ...
)
```

**Elasticsearch mapping**

```
{
 "properties": {
 ...
  "status": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
          "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
          }
      }
  },
 ...
}
```

**Data example**

```
+-----------+-----------+
| id        | status    |
+-----------+-----------+
| 452172830 | success   |
| 452172835 | other     |
| 452172840 | success   |
...
```

**More info**
**Elasticsearch mapping template**

```
PUT /_template/records_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["records"],
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
        "status": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
              }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Logstash conf**

```
input {
    jdbc {
        tags => "records"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.15:3306/esd"
        jdbc_user => "dbuser"
        jdbc_password => "dbpass"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_paging_enabled => true
        jdbc_page_size => 100000
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "select * from records order by id asc"
    }
    ...
}
output {
    if "records" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
                user => "elastic"
                password => "changeme"
                index => "records"
                template_name => "records_template"
                document_id => "%{id}"
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: You need to put the mapping before creating the index, share your mappings, logstash configuration and a sample of the data you are trying to ingest so people can try to identify what is wrong.

Comment: Updated with more info, thanks!

Comment: And how are you indexing it? What is your logstash configuration? What is the name of your index, does your index template have the same index pattern of your index? The error you are getting is because you indexed your data without a mapping template and elastic thought it was a boolean field, you need to delete the index, put the mapping template and reindex the data.

Comment: Just tried the mapping template @leandrojmp suggested (and deleted the index) -- didn't seem to help either. Not sure if I did it correctly (please see the updated post)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the field name matters somehow. If I change the select clause to something like `select status as rd_status, ...` then all the errors are gone. Not sure if there's something I miss with elasticsearch mapping or logstash internally will try to guess the data type by the name `status` (I'd be surprised if it's the latter case)